# MomentJS, FullCalendar time portions manipulation

Tags: javascript, momentjs, fullcalendar-3

I use latest fullcalendar and momentjs. My timezone is **GMT+0530**

Steps of my process is;

**Step 1)** In Fullcalendar select:func(...) I capture the date/date-range user has selected to create an event. I get the start/end dates as a moment object. If I select one day; momentjs values are;

start: **Wed Nov 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000**

end: **Thu Nov 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000**

**Question 1** - can't I make the end date to be on the same day? Otherwise Fullcalendar creates the event for 2 days. Currently I make it to work by substracting 1 day from moment (this doesn't look right).

**Step 2)** Using a slider I capture the events start/end **time**. In slider start/end are minutes from 0 to 1440 at opposite ends. I convert the selected time range to moment object by;

```
moment().startOf('day').add(start, 'minutes'); //slider's left drag
moment().startOf('day').add(end, 'minutes'); //slider's right drag
```

**Step 3)** - The time selected is set to the selected date in **Step 1** using;

```
startDate.set({ 'hour': startTime.get('hour'), 'minute': startTime.get('minute') });

endDate.set({ 'hour': endTime.get('hour'), 'minute': endTime.get('minute') });
```

Now, the event start/end's moment.toString() shows as an example;

Date 1: **Wed Nov 01 2017 07:00:00 GMT+0000**

Date 2: **Wed Nov 01 2017 12:30:00 GMT+0000** //I do a date.subtract(1, 'd') to avoid fullCalendar rendering the event to an additional day. Would like to know if there is a better way

Now the event I want is properly set to Wed Nov 01 2017 from 7AM to 12.30PM

**Question 2** In Fullcalendar view rendering is correct. But in the event array; each moment object's dates are correct **times have got reset**.

Quite frustrating... so I just set FullCalendar aside and did some tests with momentjs using the final dates that should have worked.

Date 1: **Wed Nov 01 2017 07:00:00 GMT+0000**

Date 2: **Wed Nov 01 2017 12:30:00 GMT+0000**

I convert Date 1 to a moment object by using moment(startDate, 'date');
It creates a moment object and in Console it shows the date/time as I have above. Then if I do;

```
start.hour() or start.minute() //= 0
```

Above should give me hour = 07, minute = 00 not 0 for everything?

```
start.toString() // = Mon Nov 20 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530
start.get('date') // = 20!!!!
```

But I expect it to give me back **Wed Nov 01 2017 07:00:00 GMT+0000**

**Question 3** What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're still looking for a solution I would like to help you by looking at a fiddle or snippet. FulCalendar has been officially released v4. I think it's work checking out: https://fullcalendar.io/blog/2019/03/v4-officially-released